# Internet Explorer 9 drag events block event queue

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, drag-and-drop

I am working on a project where it would be cool to have a drag and drop re orderable list.  I got this to work without too much hassle using HTML 5 Drag and Drop.  My issue is that the list can be long, and so it is virtually paged or "load on scroll" or whatever you want to call it.  This just works by reacting to the scroll event and loading more data via AJAX.

So the list has a "bump scroll" feature, i implemented this by having two normally invisible divs at the top and the bottom of the viewport.  When they receive a dragover event they just increase or decrease the scroll top of the viewport.  Pretty simple.  In the fiddle i gave them a background so you can see them.  If you try the fiddle in FF or Chrome you can see that as the ajax call completes the UI updates. This does not happen on IE.

```
dojo.byId("bumpScrollDown").connect("dragover", function(bump) {
    wrapper.scrollTop -=  20;
    dojo.xhrGet({url: "/echo/json/"}).then(function() {
        // THIS WILL NEVER FIRE on IE 9 UNTIL THE DRAG
        // OPERATION IS COMPLETED
        dojo.byId("log").innerHTML += "callback... ";
    }); 
});
```

The issue is that the drag on IE 9 seems to choke the event loop, so nothing happens - ajax callbacks, timeouts etc will not fire as long as there is a drag going on. This seems like it would screw a lot of things including animations that start on dragover etc.

Does anyone know how i could get this to work ? Can i cancel the drag event and start again ? Calling dragDrop() would start the drag again if I could somehow cancel it to allow the ajax callback to fire.

You can see on the fiddle that none of the AJAX calls triggered by a drag event will have their callbacks invoked until the drag ends.  this does not happen on chrome or FF.

http://jsfiddle.net/stevendwood/5VWZk/4/

UPDATE: it works better on IE10

Comment: So you can cancel the drag event it seems to end the dragDrop which unblocks things and  events start firing.  But i'd appreciate if anyone has any other ideas

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IE9 to test with but...

Also I might be totally wrong here but, have you tested if it's related to the *stopEvent* bit inside this code:

```
dojo.connect(wrapper, "dragover", function(ev) {
    if (!dojo.hasClass(ev.target, "noDroppy")) {
        dojo.addClass(ev.target, "dragover");
        //dojo.stopEvent(ev);
    }
});
```

**otherwise:**

I wrote similar code in jQuery recently.

My solution was to check, whether the drag was hovering over the bump, inside the dragging event itself rather than a separate hover event on the bump.

You could even check how far down or up the drag is pulled over the bumps to adjust scrollspeed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - but stopEvent on the dragover is the way you tell the HTML5 dnd API that you allow a drop, so if i remove this I can't accept any drop events, also - it doesn't make any difference anyway.  Where did you attach the dragging event you mention above ?

Comment: In jQuery I could initialize a drag object with dragstart,dragging and dragend.

Comment: Isn't it possible to add the noDroppy class to the bumps and extend the dragover event in your code to do the scrolling or is it fired only once?

Comment: the bumps have their own equivalent of the nodroppy - they do not cancel the event and listen for dragover.  "nodroppy" was just to experiment with having one thing in the list that could not accept a drop.  ondragover fires continually as you drag...for clarity - i believe it would not matter where you put either a setTimeout or some AJAX call- the point is that if you make it in a dragover event it wont be fired until the drag is completed on IE9 regardless of the length of time elapsed